# Tkinter Indentation in CheckboxTreeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I have code that generate a CheckboxTreeview
but it looks loke this

```
1
 12
   121
   122
 13
  131
```

I need it to run on larger monitor and the space look smaller...
how can I make the previous tree look like

```
1
    12
         121
         122
    13
         131
```

i found this unsolved quesion
[Python Tkinter Checkboxtreeview: how to increase its width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74423483/python-tkinter-checkboxtreeview-how-to-increase-its-width)

here some code

```
ttk.Style().configure("Treeview", background="#000000", fieldbackground="#000000", foreground="#555555", font=(None, 30), rowheight=80)
self.tests_tree = CheckboxTreeview(self.left_middle, height=int(self.height / 100), yscrollcommand=self.tree_scrollbar.set,  window_height=self.height, window_width=self.width, show="tree")
self.tests_tree.column("#0", width=int(self.width / 1.8))
self.tests_tree.insert("", "end", "Diagnostics Root", text="Diagnostics Root", open=True)
self.tests_tree.insert("Diagnostics Root", "end", "Alarm Board", text="Alarm Board", open=True)
```

Comment: The `width` option sets the width of the column in pixels. If you want to do something with the text, you can try using the `anchor` option. See: [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.column), [2](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.html#M20).

Comment: It looks like you want to shift the text on each line by a certain number of characters. The cheapest, but perhaps not the best, way is to add extra spaces to the text. E.g.: `text="    Alarm Board"`.

Comment: I have only one column because its checkbox tree (all the nodes are under the same column)

Comment: And if I add spaces before the text it doesn't look good with the checkbox
        1
            2
                             3

Comment: I think I understand what you want. Try the indent option. [ttk::style configure Treeview ?options?](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ttk%3A%3Astyle+examples). Something like: `ttk.Style().configure('Treeview', indent=100)`.